# VBA excel Concatenation Headers With column A Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of headers and Row is a list of values. I'm trying to concatenate the whole table so the header is followed by the value in row A like this -

[Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6WU4.png)

I have a loop that does this quite nicely however it has begun to take some time to work -

```
r = 2
c = 2
Do While Cells(1, r) <> ""

Do While Cells(c, 1) <> ""
    Cells(c, r) = Cells(1, r) & Cells(c, 1)
    c = c + 1
Loop
r = r + 1
c = 2
Loop
```

I've tried to use a formula instead -

```
Dim lngLastRow As Long

lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("B2:B" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=B1 & ""_"" & A2"
```

But I get the following - [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ToHn.png)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a nested loop in the code. (Unless you plan to use more columns and want to quickly expand that out without modding the code.)

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lr
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = .Cells(1, 2).Value & .Cells(i, 1).Value
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = .Cells(1, 3).Value & .Cells(i, 1).Value
            .Cells(i, 4).Value = .Cells(1, 4).Value & .Cells(i, 1).Value
        Next i
    End With
```

With dynamic columns:

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim lc As Long
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 2 To lr
            For j = 2 To lc
                .Cells(i, j).Value = .Cells(1, j).Value & .Cells(i, 1).Value
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
```

For your formula you need to set row for the access level and column for name to be absolute:

`=CONCATENATE(B$1,$A2)`

This will allow you to drag the formula around without messing up what it's grabbing